# WMD editor: where can I get the code?

Tags: javascript, wmd

I started developing an application using the WMD editor. Apparently the creator of the WMD editor has vanished from the face of the planet. Where can I find the most recent and stable version of the WMD editor that is in use on Stack Overflow?

As a side question: how do I go about securing the input given from WMD editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this isn't a joke, since that very editor was reverse-engineered and released by the Stack Overflow team here at https://github.com/cky/wmd/network

With regards to the license: *[Can I use Stack Overflow's reengineered WMD editor?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4168/can-i-use-stack-overflows-reengineered-wmd-editor)*

Comment: Not a joke; see the [stackoverflow blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/updated-wmd-editor/). The original engineer has vanished without a trace.

Comment: I was referring the question being a joke, not the release of the software by stackoverflow..

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/

Comment: That project has no actual files available for downloads... where exactly are you getting the file?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a blog post from the SO author about this:
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/wmd-editor-reverse-engineered/

Here's the reverse engineered code:

https://github.com/cky/wmd